# Rolling average with filters - Python

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe (`results`) of EPL results from the past 28 years, and I am trying to calculate the average home team points (`HPts`) from their previous 5 home games within the current season. The rows are already in chronological order. What I am effectively looking for is a version of the starter code below that partitions by `HomeTeam` and `Season` and calculates the mean of `HPts` using a window of the previous 5 rows with matching `HomeTeam` and `Season`. Clearly the existing code as written does not do what I need (it looks only at last 5 rows regardless of team and season), but is just there to show what I mean as a starting point.

```
             HomeTeam        AwayTeam Season Result  HPts  APts
0             Arsenal        Coventry   1993      A     0     3
1         Aston Villa             QPR   1993      H     3     0
2             Chelsea       Blackburn   1993      A     0     3
3           Liverpool  Sheffield Weds   1993      H     3     0
4            Man City           Leeds   1993      D     1     1
..                ...             ...    ...    ...   ...   ...
375         Liverpool  Crystal Palace   2020      H     3     0
376          Man City         Everton   2020      H     3     0
377  Sheffield United         Burnley   2020      H     3     0
378          West Ham     Southampton   2020      H     3     0
379            Wolves      Man United   2020      A     0     3

[10804 rows x 6 columns]

# Starting point for my code for home team avg points from last 5 home games
results['HomeLast5'] = results['HPts'].rolling(5).mean()
```

Anyone know how I can add a new column with the rolling average points for a given team and season? I could probably figure out a way of doing this with a loop, but I'm sure that's not going to be the most efficient way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the dataframe by `HomeTeam` and `Season`, then calculate rolling `mean` on `HPts`. Then, in order to assign the calculated mean back to the original dataframe drop the levels `0, 1` from the index so that index alignment would work properly.

```
g = results.groupby(['HomeTeam', 'Season'])['HPts']
results['HomeLast5'] = g.rolling(5).mean().droplevel([0, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks, when I tried that I initially got the following error: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.

This helped me spot a separate issue in that I hadn't reset the index after concatenating tables to create my dataframe - once I'd `reset_index()` it was fine.

Anyway, your suggestion almost does what I need, but researching further it needs `.shift()` added after `.mean()` as the average should exclude the current row.